# Acess a dataframe in dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, merge

Morning,

I have a dictionary that contains pairs of 1 keys and 2 values, at those values are dataframes

```
dictionary = {'key_1' : [df_1, df_2],
             'key_2' : [df_3, df_4], ....}
```

I want to create a new data frame (named using the key) that merges the two values of each key

```
new_df_key = pd.merge(left = df_1,
                      right = df_2,
                      how = 'left',
                      on = 'column_name')
```

I having trouble retrieving the name of the data frames to do the merge. The goal is to iterate through the keys and values in the dictionary and create new data frames. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: hey can you please add your sample data set here and the expected output sample?  just put a sample with 2 rows, it is more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain I'm understanding the question correctly, but I think you may want to do something like this.

```
merged_df_list = []
for key in dictionary.keys():
    df1, df2 = dictionary[key][0], dictionary[key][1]
    key = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, how = "left", on = "column_name")
    merged_df_list.append(key)
```

This should give you a list of merged dataframes named by the keys in the dictionary

Edit:

Created using dictionary instead so can access the merged_dfs by the key name:

```
merged_df_dict = {}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    df1, df2 = dictionary[key][0], dictionary[key][1]
    merged_df = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, how = "left", on = "column_name")
    merged_df_dict[key] = merged_df
```

This should allow you to access the new df by the keyname by:

```
merged_df_dict[keyname] # Returns the new df merged by that key
```

Comment: Perfect Sam! The merged_df_list has a bunch of dataframes. Aren't they saved in a variable with the key name? I can access them without using:

```
merged_df_list[0]
```
for example

Comment: Just edited to use dictionary instead as this makes more sense.

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot Sam, you just solved a doubt I had for a long time! Thank you

Comment: Sam, do you mind if I elaborate this a little further?

Comment: Not at all, go for it!

Comment: I may  asking more than I can get! 

I was hoping that instead I access the dataframe using  merged_df_dict[keyname], I could create dataframes myself

new_df_key = merged_df_dict[keyname].

The question is, can I create iterate and create empty df? I know how to generate names, put they are strings. Is it clear?

Comment: So you'd like to iterate thought all the data frames and assign them to variables by the key name? If so may I ask for what purpose as there may be another solution as I do not believe this to be possible (or I don't know how).

Comment: Yes, that is it. Merging the dataframes (df1 and df2, etc) is mandatory. ,Each dataframe (df1 and df2) represents a day in time, and I need one merged_df for each day. 
I'am analyzing a time period of 2 weeks for now, I can increase it if I can make these transformations we have been talking about in an efficient way.

Comment: Sadly I'm afraid I don't know how to do that, I actually believe it isn't possible to iterate through something and assign a new variable for each object. The best idea would be to iterate through and apply whatever analysis you need done to each dataframe by a function.

Comment: I was afraid you said that :D But no problem, this was already a major step ;) Thanks a lot!